# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Cron Job not picking up environment variables

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, fastapi

I am deploying a FastAPI application using ElasticBeanstalk. Part of my what I would like to do, is to have a script to collect some data and post it on an RDS postgres database using a cron job. After some digging, I managed to get the cron job to work, but not fully.

The script to post data uses the RDS_USERNAME... environment variables. I have the following configs files:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "main:app"
  commands:
    setvars:
        command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/local.sh
packages:
    yum:
        jq: []
container_commands:
  01_initdb:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 init_db.py"
    leader_only: true
  02_some_cron_job:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cron_job.txt > /etc/cron.d/cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron_job"
    leader_only: true
```

I have a command that reads the AWS enviroment variables and sets them to the session.

The cron as I have said is running. This is the error I get from the /var/log/cron:

`CMDOUT (KeyError: 'RDS_USERNAME')`

The python file that is connecting to the database:

```
DATABASE_URL = \
        'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(
            username=os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            password=os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            host=os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            port=os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
            database=os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        )
```

And this is the cron_job.txt file:

`* * * * * ec2-user /var/app/venv/*/bin/python3 /var/app/current/cron.py`